# Problema con redireccionamiento apache2 Linux

Tags: linux, web, .htaccess, apache2, redirección

Tengo instalado apache2, mysql-server y mysql-client para la pagina web.

Anteriormente trabajaba en windows pero siempre he tenido linux instalado en el pc, me gusta mas. Hace días por inconvenientes con mi pc me vi obligado a utilizar un pc con pocos recursos el cual windows lo mataba.

Instale Linux, pero al momento de configurar las herramientas para trabajar en las web no logro configurar correctamente el servidor apache2.

El servidor local muestra mi sitio web index.php, no muestra el footer ni el aside que están en `/includes/aside.php` los cuales he pasado de la siguiente forma `<?php include('/includes/aside.php'); ?>` noto también que los archivos javascript tampoco los esta leyendo.

Dejo las configuraciones que tengo en el archivo `tucolmenavirtual.conf`

```
<VirtualHost tucolmenavirtual/*:80>
 ServerAdmin root@localhost
 ServerAlias tucolmenavirtual/
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tucolmenavirtual
</VirtualHost>
```

archivo .htaccess ubicado en `/var/www/html/tucolmenavirtual/`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

# PRODUCCION REDIRECCIONA TODO A LA URL SIN WWW
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tucolmenavirtual\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.tucolmenavirtual\.com
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ^https\:\/\/tucolmenavirtual\.com\/$1 [R=301,L]

# PRODUCCION REDIRECCIONA A HTTPS TODAS LAS URL
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# PRODUCCION URL AMIGABLES
#RewriteRule ^producto/(.*)/(.*)$ producto.php?p=$1&i=$2 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^catalogo/(.*)$ catalogo.php?i=$1 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^busqueda/(.*)$ busqueda.php?i=$1 [QSA,L]

# SERVIDOR LOCAL URL AMIGABLES
RewriteRule ^producto.php/(.*)/(.*)$ producto.php?p=$1&i=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^catalogo.php/(.*)$ catalogo.php?i=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^busqueda.php/(.*)$ busqueda.php?i=$1 [QSA,L]

# ELIMINA EL .PHP AL FINAL DE LOS ARCHIVOS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Este archivo htaccess me ha funcionado perfectamente en el servidor local (windows) y en el servidor de producción

Ya habilite el re-direccionamiento `a2enmod rewrite`

Pagina principal
[image: pagina principal(error-no_carga_footer_ni_aside)]

Al ir a otra pagina
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado buscando tutoriales, videos, foros pero en todos hacen lo que ya tengo configurado (archivo .conf, habilitar re-direccionamiento) pero no me funciona.

Gracias de antemano, estaré atento por si requieren algún archivo adicional.

Answer (score 0):

No soy experto en apache, pero veo algunas cosas que creo que no cuadran y que te permitirán avanzar en la investigación:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost

`<VirtualHost addr[:port]>...</VirtualHost>`

Lo que tienes puesto en ese bloque es en vez de `direccion-ip:puerto` es un `nombre de dominio:puerto`. Creo que ese es el **primer** problema. De pronto tendría que ser `*:80`?

Supongo que dentro de ese bloque, tienes que especificar el `ServerName` para que apache sepa que cuando le lleguen peticiones de `http://tucolmenavirtual.com`, use la configuración de ese VirtualHost.

Otro problema que veo es que para tratar de ver el contenido, estás usando `http://localhost`, cosa que no va a funcionar si quieres ver lo que hace el `VirtualHost`. La petición a apache tiene que llegar con el nombre de dominio que estás configurando en el VirtualHost, o sea `tucolmenavirtual.com`.... lo cual me lleva al otro punto a considerar: Ya tienes hecha la configuración de DNS para que cuando trate de resolver el nombre, llegue al servidor adecuado? Si la respuesta es "Eso viene más adelante", entonces te toca configurar tu equipo *local* para que cuando solicites el nombre `tucolmenavirtual.com`, resuelva a 127.0.0.1 (si estás probando navegando en el propio servidor). Si es un linux, eso se hace facilmente colocando un item en el archivo `/etc/hosts`.... si es un güindous, no tengo la menor idea de como se hace esto.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Al hacer esos cambios sigo con el mismo inconveniente, reinicio apache y todo sigue igual. El index lo lee perfectamentemente pero el resto de archivos que estén en subcarpetas no.

Comment: Si, bueno.... al principio decía que te va a permitir _continuar_ con la investigación. Que cosas te dice el log luego de hacer esos ajustes? (Por lo que veo justo ahora, se puede utilizar apachetop para analizar que está pasando https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-and-use-apachetop/)